# How to ignore the line break while printing a string read from stdin?

Tags: input, printing, rust

I tried to write a bit of code which reads a name from stdin and prints it. The problem is the line breaks immediately after printing the variable and the characters following the variable are printed in the next line:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter your name:");
    let mut name = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut name).expect("Failed To read Input");
    println!("Hello '{}'!", name);
}
```

The '!' is printed in the next line, which is not the expected location.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Use [`.trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) to remove whitespace on a string. This example should work.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter your name:");
    let mut name = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut name).expect("Failed To read Input");
    println!("Hello '{}'!", name.trim());
}
```

There also [`trim_start()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_start) and [`.trim_end()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end) if you need to remove whitespace changes from only one side of the string.

Comment: io::stdin().read_line() does not preprocess the line read, so a '\n' remains at the end. So it needs the extra trim() call, though ideally read_line() as it name suggests should do this by itself in order to provide better api to users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the last character only (in this case is newline character), you should use [`.pop()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) instead of [`.trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim).

When you use `.trim()`, the leading and trailing whitespace(s) will be removed, so the space, tab, newline, and the other whitespace in the beginning and the end of the string will be removed.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter your name:");
    let mut name = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut name).expect("Failed To read Input");
    name.pop();
    println!("Hello '{}'!", name);
}
```

Comment: This does not handle the case when the newline is multiple characters, such as when it's `\r\n`.

Comment: I believe `trim_end()` is the correct solution for this.