# Where do I find the complexity of an operation?

Tags: rust

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46290728/1994377) it is mentioned that for a string doing 
`s.chars().count()` to get the number of characters is an O(n) operation.
For simple ASCII strings getting the number of bytes using `s.len()` works as well. When using a check to make sure that all those bytes are actually ASCII this is probably safe.

I want to know what the complexity of that operation is. It might still have to find the end of the string like in C and be O(n).

I tried to look it up and found the [documentation of the `std::string::String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.len),
 which applies for appropriate `s`. However it doesn't state its complexity. Looking at the source it just does this `self.vec.len()`. So we go to look at the [vector docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.len) and find that this simply returns a stored length `self.len` meaning that this is indeed an O(1) operation.

That was a lot of work though. Now what about the case that `s` is a [std::str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/)? I tried to do the same but got stuck in [this mess](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~cs146a/rust/doc-02-21-2015/nightly/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#1327-1367).

Is there a more easily accessible ressource for operation complexities in Rust?

Something like this [list for Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) would be great.

Comment: Note that checking that all characters are ascii is O(n) just like `s.chars().count()`, so unless you need the check for another reason, you might as well use `s.chars().count()`.

Comment: Complexities should be documented for all datatypes.  Where they are missing, feel free to send a PR or file an issue.  I don't think a centralized list with all complexities is the right place for this; this only makes sense for collections, where you need an overview to decide which collection to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other than the [performance section on collections](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/index.html#performance) I don't think there currently is a common list like the Python one you referenced.

As for `str`, determining its length is an O(1) operation, because [a string slice consists of a pointer and length](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#representation):

```
// We can re-build a str out of ptr and len. This is all unsafe because
// we are responsible for making sure the two components are valid:
let s = unsafe {
    // First, we build a &[u8]...
    let slice = slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len);

    // ... and then convert that slice into a string slice
    str::from_utf8(slice)
};
```

Comment: To be precise, `str::len` determines the length in code units (just like `String::len`). To get the length in code points, you need to call `str::chars::count` which is O(1) (same as for a `String`).

Comment: @Jmb I know you mean O(n), but just figured I'd mention it in case somebody else came along and was confused :)

Answer (score 3):

`String` and `str` offer the same complexity guarantees for all actions. In fact, most operations on `String` (including `chars()`) [are actually operations on `str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref-methods) that use the implicit conversion from `String` to `str` (that conversion is free since they share the same low-level representation).