# get console width of char

Tags: rust, unicode, terminal, console

In rust, how can I get the console ("terminal") width of a character (`char`)?

I want the "column width" as displayed in a console. Typically this is found by counting characters in the string; [`s.chars().count()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46290728/471376). However some Unicode characters are more than one column width wide. Some are "full width" and others are visually large characters that require multiple console columns.

A few examples

```rust
fn main() {
    // ASCII 'A'
    let c: char = '\u{41}';
    println!("{:?} len_utf8 {} len_utf16 {} as u128 0x{:08X}", c, c.len_utf8(), c.len_utf16(), c as u128);
    // full-width Ａ
    let c: char = '\u{FF21}';
    println!("{:?} len_utf8 {} len_utf16 {} as u128 0x{:08X}", c, c.len_utf8(), c.len_utf16(), c as u128);
    // visually wide char NEW MOON WITH FACE
    let c: char = '\u{1F31A}';
    println!("{:?} len_utf8 {} len_utf16 {} as u128 0x{:08X}", c, c.len_utf8(), c.len_utf16(), c as u128);
}
```

([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=63bb72124c6667ad319fe8301c3acdcf))

Prints

```
'A' len_utf8 1 len_utf16 1 as u128 0x00000041
'Ａ' len_utf8 3 len_utf16 1 as u128 0x0000FF21
'' len_utf8 4 len_utf16 2 as u128 0x0001F31A
```

Character ['LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A' A (U+0041)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0041/index.htm)  is displayed *one* console columns wide.

Character ['FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A' Ａ (U+FF21)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff21/index.htm) is displayed *two* console columns wide.

Character ['NEW MOON WITH FACE'  (U+1F31A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f31a/index.htm) is displayed *three* console columns wide.

In rust, how can I find a `char` console column width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `unicode_width` crate. Docs: https://docs.rs/unicode-width/latest/unicode_width/